# React Router v6 index routes giving trailing slash error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, jsx

I'm using react router v6 and I'm having trouble with correctly using index routes. I have the following top level routes which all work fine *except* navigating to `"/"`.

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/" element={<DefaultPage />}>
    <Route path="profile/*" element={<UserProfile account={true} />} />
    <Route path="register/*" element={<UserProfile account={true} register={true} />} />
    <Route path="user/:username/profile" element={<UserProfile />} />
    {/*<Route path="account*" element={"Account"} />*/}
    <Route path="feed/:slug/*" element={<StreamPage type="feed" />} />
    <Route path="user/:slug/*" element={<StreamPage type="user" />}  />
    <Route path="post/edit" element={<PostEditorPage  />}  />
    <Route path="post/edit/:id" element={<PostEditorPage  />}  />
    <Route path="publication/edit" element={<PubEditorPage  />}  />
    <Route path="publication/edit/:slug" element={<PubEditorPage  />}  />
    <Route path="publication/:id" element={<PubPage  />}  />
    <Route index element={<StreamPage index={true} />} />
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

When I go to the root url `<StreamPage index={true} />` renders as expected using the `Outlet` specified in `DefaultPage` but I get the following warning:

> You rendered descendant `<Routes>` (or called `useRoutes()`) at "/" (under `<Route path="">`) but the parent route path has no trailing "*". This means if you navigate deeper, the parent won't match anymore and therefore the child routes will never render.

> Please change the parent `<Route path="">` to `<Route path="/*">`."

This doesn't seem to happen with any of the other routes and when index is true `StreamPage` doesn't render any child routes so the problem has to be here but my code seems to resemble the examples from [the docs](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview) pretty closely so I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Thoughts?

**Note that** the warning persists if I change the top line to
`<Route path="/*" element={<DefaultPage />}>`

For completness here is the relevant part of StreamPage

EDIT: Added the top Routes section thanks to help from comments identifying that there was a missing piece to generate the warning.

```
        <Routes>
            <Route index element={<StreamSidebar/> } />
            <Route path="post/:subslug/*" element={<Sidebar/> }/>
        </Routes>
             {index && <Stream stream={stream} index={index} />}
                {!index &&
                    <Routes>
                            <Route index element={<Stream stream={stream} index={index} />}/>
                            <Route path="post/:subslug/*" element={<PostPage stream={stream}  />}/>
                     </Routes>}
```

(I can include the full thing if necessary but this is the only part with routes in it and even those shouldn't render when index is true)
}

Comment: Could you include all the relevant code you are working with that reproduces the issue? It sounds like `StreamPage` component renders a `Routes` component with some nested routes. Can we see that code? If possible, could you try creating a *running* codesandbox demo that reproduces this issue that we could inspect and debug live?

Comment: Yes, of course I'll add that code but I think I was unclear.  It *doesn't* render any nested routes when index is true  and I think I tested it without any Routes in StreamPage at all but I'll include it all the same since I could be being dumb.

Comment: I can't reproduce the specific error/warning you mention here in a running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-v6-index-routes-giving-trailing-slash-error-jc2ilm), but I do think your routes are configured a little oddly. The index route rendering  `StreamPage` is passed an `index` prop so it renders `Stream`, otherwise, it can render the nested routes when it's not the index route like `"feed/:slug/*"`. Does `Stream` component render more nested routes? Can you provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Basically it seems we haven't found the exact route that is causing the issue. The warning says something about a route with an empty string path, i.e. `<Route path="">`. Is there something like that in your code somewhere?

Comment: I didn't think Stream rendered any more nested routes but it turned out I was passing a component as an argument that did.  Still don't understand the issue though.  Here's a MCVE https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-v6-index-routes-giving-trailing-slash-error-forked-ctw60v?file=/src/App.js:1590-2699

Comment: What is the purpose of the `StreamPageInternal` component? It sort of looks like you are wanting to conditionally render different sidebar components depending on the route. Is this correct?

Comment: It's not necessary for the MVCE (in the real code it's to tell react that I want a different copy of the component whenever the param it digests from the path changes for purposes of initializing using React.useState(init funcion)...its probably not the best way to write the code).  I've removed it from the sandbox.

Comment: Ohh, but that can probably be removed from the MVCE...let me check

Comment: I've narrowed it down to the `Routes` component rendering the routes for `StreamSidebar` and `Sidebar` causing the issue. These seem like they could be rendered as part of a layout route, but I'm unsure if you still want them rendered when the `StreamPage` component isn't an index.

Comment: Thx, that's at least tells me how to create minimal solution which would have taken forever without your help!  I still wish I knew what I was doing wrong.  (The reason I'm not rendering them as part of a layout route is that my code in StreamPage (well StreamPageInternal) actually looks like:  <StdLayout sidebar={Sidebar}> with those extra routes being inside the Sidebar component but for now I'm just passing index down there and skipping routes in index case to avoid warning)

Comment: "any idea what I should avoid so I don't run into this again?" - That's funny, and why I'm asking so many questions trying to figure out what you want to code to do. I think the biggest issue, IMO, is the double use of the `StreamPage` on the root `"/"` route and in nested routes, or rather, the coupling of it to the conditional rendering of the different sub-routes. I'd probably try refactoring a bit so `StreamPage` is a layout route component, renders the sidebars based on the `index` prop, and renders an `Outlet` for wrapped routes.

Comment: Thx for the suggestion.  I'll probably do that.   I meant something like: don't put an index Route as a subroute of an index Route.  Like, what part of the API of reactrouter am I violating.  But this is more than enough to actually solve the specific problem so thanks so much. (Sorry I couldn't explain better but I'm stripping out a ton of code related to data fetching and mobx observables)

Comment: check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71997440/changed-syntax-in-react-route-dom-from-switch-to-routes-but-still-no-display/71997599#71997599

Comment: @Tomak Maybe I'm being dense, but I'm not seeing the relevance.  Isn't the problem there simply that the code isn't using the new element= syntax?

Answer (score 1):

[@Drew Reese's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8690857/drew-reese) responses answered the primary issue I was having with this code so I'm marking this as answered.  What rule this code violates seemed different enough that I created a separate [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72199595/react-router-v6-warning-on-nested-index-routes) that gives a really minimal example of how sibling nested index routes generate the warning and avoids all the confusion about what the heck all this other stuff is doing.

Answer (score 0):

its maybe for use of /* in your route and if you will be  deep in path of your route may cause of problem