# React Router v6 warning on nested index routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

The following code ([codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-v6-index-routes-giving-trailing-slash-error-forked-150l0s?file=/src/App.js:52-541)) produces this warning when the root url is navigated to:

> You rendered descendant  (or called `useRoutes()`) at "/" (under `<Route path="">`) but the parent route path has no trailing "*"...

However, no warning is issued if I navigate to "/post/blah".

```
import { Routes, Route} from "react-router-dom";



const StreamPage = () => (
  <>
        <Routes>
            <Route index element={<div /> } />
            <Route path="post/:subslug/*" element={<div /> }/>
        </Routes>

      <Routes>
        <Route index element={<div />} />
        <Route path="post/:subslug/*" element={<div />} />
      </Routes>
  </>
)


export const App = () => (
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" >
          <Route path="post/*" element={<StreamPage  />} />
          <Route index element={<StreamPage />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
  )
```

I know, I could fix the code by merging the two Routes blocks in StreamPage but I'm asking if this is expected behavior and if so what part of the react-router usage contract/API I'm violating?  For instance, am I not allowed to have don't have sibling index routes under an index route?  If I don't understand when/why this warning is produced I won't be able to avoid it in the future.

(related to this earlier [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72195066/react-router-v6-index-routes-giving-trailing-slash-error/72199691#72199691))

Comment: Obviously, here I could just merge the two Routes sections in StreamPage but in the code this came up in these Routes blocks are actually buried in their own sub-components and I thought one of the advantages of react-router v6 was that I could put this kind of readable Routes language in the components that needed it rather than pass down/useContext the results of route matching up top.